# how to plot a custom array in amibroker

Tags: amibroker

I'm using dotnetforAmibroker to create a DLL to for a function to plot the data.
I have a yearly divident database of many symbols and i want to plot the yearly divident values based on the symbol. How can I do it?

[yearly dividents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyBBG.png)

I tried to search on Internet but no luck. I'm new to amibroker.